# grep for all the lines that doest not have a particular word

Tags: grep

I have a file fileA.txt

```
Batman.plist
Green Arrow.plist
Hawkgirl.plist
EOPrototypes.plist
Person.plist
EOPrototypes.plist
EOJavellinPrototypes.plist
Sinestro
Slomon Grundy.plist
Batman Beyond.plist
EORedRobin
EORavenPrototypes.plist
```

Now if I want to get all the lines that end with `plist` and does not contain the word `Prototype`. So far I have

```
grep -v "Prototype" fileA.txt | grep -E "*plist$"
```

And the output is

```
Batman.plist
Green Arrow.plist
Hawkgirl.plist
Person.plist
Slomon Grundy.plist
Batman Beyond.plist
```

Which is exactly what I want,

But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The second half should just be `grep 'plist$'`. `*` isn't a shell glob in a regex, and it's unnecessary, and there's nothing there that needs an ERE.

Comment: What do you mean by ERE ?

Comment: Extended Regular Expression, which is why you would use the `-E` flag.

Comment: I knew Extended Regular Expression, never used ERE before :$ But now I know what it stands for ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
grep -v Prototype | grep 'plist$'
```

is probably as good as it gets. You could do it with one command with `sed` or `awk` (or with non-standard extensions to `grep` as others have already shown):

```
sed '/Prototype/d;/plist$/!d'
```

Or

```
awk '/plist$/ && ! /Prototype/'
```

But that's not necessarily going to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
grep -P '^(?!.*Prototype).*plist$' fileA.txt
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. I missed a `Prototype.plist` in testing set.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Prototypes` string always exactly prefixes the `.plist` string as shown in your example, and your platform's version of grep supports PCRE mode, you could use a perl-style negative lookbehind such as `grep -P '(?<!Prototypes)\.plist$'` e.g.

```
$ grep -P '(?<!Prototypes)\.plist$' fileA.txt
Batman.plist
Green Arrow.plist
Hawkgirl.plist
Person.plist
Slomon Grundy.plist
Batman Beyond.plist
```

Comment: N.B. `grep` on OSX >= 10.8 doesn't include `-P`.